# How to remove certain columns/elements from a .log file?

Tags: java, parsing, netbeans

I want to remove certain log entries to parse out the file. However I got an error from the code in which I ran with the .replaceAll method while running BufferedReader and other imported functions and libraries. How do I go about removing the "rule_uid: {C1336766-9489-4049-9817-50584D83A245};" without causing the error?

Log File:

```
Jan 1 22:54:17 drop   %LOGSOURCE% >eth1 rule: 7; rule_uid: {C1336766-9489-4049-9817-50584D83A245};
Jan 1 22:54:22 drop   %LOGSOURCE% >eth1 rule: 7; rule_uid: {C1336766-9489-4049-9817-50584D83A245};
Jan 1 22:54:23 drop   %LOGSOURCE% >eth1 rule: 7; rule_uid: {C1336766-9489-4049-9817-50584D83A245};
Jan 1 22:54:41 drop   %LOGSOURCE% >eth1 rule: 7; rule_uid: {C1336766-9489-4049-9817-50584D83A245};
```

Error:

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 9
rule_uid: {C1336766-9489-4049-9817-50584D83A245};" (which is at the .replaceAll() method for rule_uid column)
```

Code:

```
try {
        File file = new    File("filename");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line = "", oldtext = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            oldtext += line + "\r\n";
        }
        reader.close();
        // replace a word in a file
        String newtext = oldtext.replaceAll("%LOGSOURCE% >eth1 rule: 7;", "");
        String newtext1 = oldtext.replaceAll("rule_uid: {C1336766-9489-4049-9817-50584D83A245};", "");

     //To replace a line in a file
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("newfilename");
        writer.write(newtext);
        writer.write(newtext1);
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: May I suggest that you consider using a logging framework like `log4j` instead of trying to write logs yourself? Using a framework will likely also take care of the problem of more than one thread trying to read/write to the log file at the same time.

Comment: Ah but this is a sample which was given to me for a project so there is no way I can change anything in this log file. I didn't write this log file on my own. @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have special characters in the input string in your second call to `replaceAll()` which are interpreted as being part of the regular expression syntax, rather than plain text to be replaced.  Once I escaped these special characters in IntelliJ, the compiler errors went away.

Change this:

```
String newtext = oldtext.replaceAll("%LOGSOURCE% >eth1 rule: 7;", "");
String newtext1 = oldtext.replaceAll("rule_uid: {C1336766-9489-4049-9817-50584D83A245};", "");
```

To this:

```
String newtext = oldtext.replaceAll("%LOGSOURCE% >eth1 rule: 7;", "");
String newtext1 = oldtext.replaceAll("rule_uid: \\{C1336766-9489-4049-9817-50584D83A245\\};", "");
```

All I did was to escape the curly braces with two leading backslashes, e.g. `\\{`

**Update:**

You have a few other logical problems in your code.  Here is the complete code I recommend that you use:

```
try {
    File file = new File("filename");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line = "", oldtext = "";
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        oldtext += line + "\r\n";
    }
    reader.close();

    // replace a word in a file
    oldtext = oldtext.replaceAll("%LOGSOURCE% >eth1 rule: 7;", "");
    oldtext = oldtext.replaceAll("rule_uid: \\{C1336766-9489-4049-9817-50584D83A245\\};", "");

    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("newfilename");

    // the entire file is contained within the String 'oldtext'
    // you only need one write operation to output it
    writer.write(oldtext);
    writer.close();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Now the compiler does not show any error however the output file did not have any changes.

Comment: The replacements are working for me.  Are you _sure_ that the output file is not changing?  Maybe you need to rebuild your project.

Comment: Thank you! I did learn something here. I understood your code and I guess I didn't really need another 'oldtext' for seperate columns. Thanks! Silly mistake on my part.